# More Loss in Training than Testing using multi-layer LSTM Neural Networkin Keras/TF

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, lstm, keras

Unsure why I'm consistently seeing a higher training loss than test loss in my model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(train_X,train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=30, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The plot this produces:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You may not be doing anything wrong, this happens sufficiently frequently that is covered in the [Keras FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#why-is-the-training-loss-much-higher-than-the-testing-loss). The FAQ give at two common possibilities:

1. Dropout (and other types of regularisation) are turned off during testing, or
2. Training loss is calculated over the whole epoch while test loss is calculated only at the end.

If neither of these explain your situation, there are some tips for debugging neural networks in [this Github issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1761).